# php imagecreatefromjpeg not working

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, so this might be an easy one.
I just want to display an image once it is uploaded and sent to the script by POST. But I am not able to see the image.

Please find the code below:
Name of the php file is test.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    if(isset($_FILES['photo'])
    && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
    && $_FILES['photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){

        if ($_FILES['photo']['type']=='image/jpeg') {

            $tmp_img = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_img);
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($image,'',90);
            imagedestroy($image); 

        }else{
            echo "Uploaded file was not JPEG","</br>";
        }   
    }else{
        echo "No file uploaded","</br>";

    }
}else{
    ?>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="photo">Photo : </label>
        <input type="file" name="photo"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload a JPEG photo"/>
    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You have [`PHP GD`](http://www.php.net/manual/es/book.image.php) installed?

Answer (score 5):

Do you get any errors?

Is GD installed? `imagecreatefromjpeg` is a GD method.

http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass NULL here:

```
        imagejpeg($image,NULL,90);
```

From the documentation under `Parameters`:

```
filename

  The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.

  To skip this argument in order to provide the quality parameter, use NULL.
```